Display layout for a tree-like diagram
I am doing a project to display an org chart/flow and I want when I press a "Set layout" button to arrange the nodes in a strutured way, like from image 1 where they are scattered to image 2 where they have a form.
I have used dagrejs or cytoscape to do this but there is a problem when 2 nodes are partners(they are on the same level and they are not child to one another). The nodes I am talking about can be seen in 2nd image above the red line. 
The structure of all my nodes and edges is like this:
    "nodes-departments": [
    {
      "id": "4a14",
      "type": "input",
      "level": 0,
      "children": [
        "a58e",
        "aff0"
      ],
      "position": {
        "x": 420,
        "y": 40
      },
      "data": {
        "slug": "it",
        "name": "IT",
        "occupied": 11,
        "available": 11,
        "id": "4a14"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "2fc6",
      "type": "default",
      "level": 3,
      "children": [],
      "position": {
        "x": 660,
        "y": 780
      },
      "data": {
        "slug": "rnd",
        "name": "R&D",
        "occupied": 4,
        "available": 6,
        "id": "2fc6"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "a58e",
      "type": "default",
      "level": 1,
      "children": [],
      "position": {
        "x": 180,
        "y": 320
      },
      "data": {
        "slug": "hr",
        "name": "HR",
        "occupied": 8,
        "available": 12,
        "id": "a58e"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "aff0",
      "type": "default",
      "level": 1,
      "children": [
        "8e40",
        "9cd4",
        "2de7"
      ],
      "position": {
        "x": 660,
        "y": 320
      },
      "data": {
        "slug": "finance",
        "name": "Finance",
        "occupied": 5,
        "available": 10,
        "id": "aff0"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "2de7",
      "type": "default",
      "level": 2,
      "children": [
        "2fc6"
      ],
      "position": {
        "x": 660,
        "y": 560
      },
      "data": {
        "slug": "marketing",
        "name": "Marketing",
        "occupied": 7,
        "available": 14,
        "id": "2de7"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "8e40",
      "type": "default",
      "level": 2,
      "children": [],
      "position": {
        "x": 400,
        "y": 560
      },
      "data": {
        "slug": "sales",
        "name": "Sales",
        "occupied": 12,
        "available": 8,
        "id": "8e40"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "9cd4",
      "type": "default",
      "level": 2,
      "children": [],
      "position": {
        "x": 940,
        "y": 560
      },
      "data": {
        "slug": "support",
        "name": "Support",
        "occupied": 6,
        "available": 9,
        "id": "9cd4"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "19f0",
      "type": "default",
      "level": 2,
      "children": [],
      "position": {
        "x": 1220,
        "y": 560
      },
      "data": {
        "slug": "administration",
        "name": "Administration",
        "occupied": 11,
        "available": 7,
        "id": "19f0"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "d017",
      "type": "default",
      "level": 3,
      "children": [],
      "position": {
        "x": 940,
        "y": 780
      },
      "data": {
        "id": "d017",
        "name": "test",
        "available": 123,
        "occupied": 321,
        "slug": "slug4"
      }
    }
  ],
  "edges-departments": [
    {
      "id": "e4a14->a58e",
      "source": "4a14",
      "target": "a58e",
      "type": "custom",
      "targetHandle": "top",
      "sourceHandle": "bottom",
      "markerEnd": "arrowclosed"
    },
    {
      "id": "eaff0->2de7",
      "source": "aff0",
      "target": "2de7",
      "type": "custom",
      "sourceHandle": "bottom",
      "targetHandle": "top",
      "markerEnd": "arrowclosed"
    },
    {
      "id": "e4a14->aff0",
      "source": "4a14",
      "target": "aff0",
      "type": "custom",
      "targetHandle": "top",
      "sourceHandle": "bottom",
      "markerEnd": "arrowclosed"
    },
    {
      "id": "e2de7->2fc6",
      "source": "2de7",
      "target": "2fc6",
      "type": "custom",
      "sourceHandle": "bottom",
      "targetHandle": "top",
      "markerEnd": "arrowclosed"
    },
    {
      "id": "eaff0->8e40",
      "source": "aff0",
      "target": "8e40",
      "type": "custom",
      "targetHandle": "top",
      "sourceHandle": "bottom",
      "markerEnd": "arrowclosed"
    },
    {
      "id": "eaff0->9cd4",
      "source": "aff0",
      "target": "9cd4",
      "type": "custom",
      "targetHandle": "top",
      "sourceHandle": "bottom",
      "markerEnd": "arrowclosed"
    },
    {
      "id": "e9cd4->19f0",
      "source": "9cd4",
      "target": "19f0",
      "sourceHandle": "right-source",
      "targetHandle": "left-target",
      "type": "custom",
      "markerEnd": ""
    },
    {
      "id": "e9cd4->d017",
      "source": "9cd4",
      "target": "d017",
      "type": "custom",
      "targetHandle": "top",
      "sourceHandle": "bottom",
      "markerEnd": "arrowclosed"
    }
  ],

Those 2 libraries are putting the Administration node below the Support one even for other types like: klay. Do you know if there is way to configure one of those libraries to achieve this? Maybe I missed something in docs or if there is any algorithm to achieve this or an idea how to do my own layout. I tried to think about something using the levels and based on the level with most nodes go from there bottom and up to make the structure but I get stuck when I try to figure out how to recalculate the positions for the nodes in each level.
Those 2 libraries are putting the Administration node below the Support one even for other types like: klay. Do you know if there is way to configure one of those libraries to achieve this? Maybe I missed something in docs or if there is any algorithm to achieve this or an idea how to do my own layout. I tried to think about something using the levels and based on the level with most nodes go from there bottom and up to make the structure but I get stuck when I try to figure out how to recalculate the positions for the nodes in each level.

I mean not necessary, there could be a thrid party that is an associate/partner with one department but should be included in the chart. In that case it doesn't have a parent cause it does not make part of the initial hierarchy.

You can use BALKAN OrgChartJS it does support Partner nodes, here is the documentation


I was using Balkan OrgChartJS at that time but for now I decided to halt the layout feature and to focus on other things. I will try to play again with it in the future. Thanks anyway.
